# inserting keys and values though for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to get some data from a localhost website,

```
#scrapy shell localhost.aspx

for i in response.xpath('//*[text()="Core Units"]/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/div'):
    i.xpath('.//text()').extract()
```

this is the output

```
['Core Units']
['AB43342', 'Identify learning objectives']
['Elective Units']
['AB43343', 'Engage with texts for personal purposes']
['AB43344', 'Engage with texts for learning purposes']
['AB43345', 'Engage with texts for employment purposes']
['AB43346', 'Engage with texts to participate in the community']
['Extra Units']
['AB43348', 'Create  texts for personal purposes']
['AB43349', 'Create  texts for learning purposes']
['AB43350', 'Create  texts for employment purposes']
```

I want to create 1 dictionary as follows:

```
di={'Core Units':['Code:AB4334 desc: Identify learning objectives'],
'Elective Units':['Code: AB43343 desc: Engage with texts for personal purposes',
'Code: AB43344 desc:Engage with texts for learning purposes',
...,]
'Extra Units': ['Code: AB43348 desc: Create  texts for personal purposes',
...]
}
```

I do not know what are the keys which might show up so I can't create an empty dictionary and start filling it, I have to take them from the for loop

Comment: a dict can't have the same key multiple times so that wouldn't work ie you can't have this `'Elective Units':'Code: AB43343 desc: Engage with texts for personal purposes'
'Elective Units':'Code: AB43344 desc:Engage with texts for learning purposes',`

Comment: @NileshKesar I am sorry I fixed that it fine if I put them as a list

Comment: I can do something really simple for you but it will only work for this case and only if you have 1 item first

Comment: @NileshKesar I can't guarantee that

Comment: why is your data returning like that in the first place?

Comment: have you tried using a different XPATH to make this easier for you

Comment: @NileshKesar i am in terminal, I am not sure I understand your question

Comment: ahhh ok makes sense I was confused at why you were getting data formatted in that way. but makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
result = {}
for i in response.xpath('//*[text()="Core Units"]/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/div'):
    line=i.xpath('.//text()').extract()
    if len(line) == 1 :
        last_key = line[0]
        result[last_key] = []
    else :
        result[last_key].append("Code:" + line[0] + " desc: " + line[1])
```

Comment: you mean I should create an empty string and fill it (in the for loop), then use this function right?

Comment: there's no need to create a string , can you have each line by iterating over something in a loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: uses [`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) formatting from Python 3.6

Here's something that should help with the given information.

```
inp = [['Core Units'],
       ['AB43342', 'Identify learning objectives'],
       ['Elective Units'],
       ['AB43343', 'Engage with texts for personal purposes'],
       ['AB43344', 'Engage with texts for learning purposes'],
       ['AB43345', 'Engage with texts for employment purposes'],
       ['AB43346', 'Engage with texts to participate in the community'],
       ['Extra Units'],
       ['AB43348', 'Create  texts for personal purposes'],
       ['AB43349', 'Create  texts for learning purposes'],
       ['AB43350', 'Create  texts for employment purposes']]

from collections import defaultdict
di = defaultdict(list)    # Helpful to just append value to new key in dict
unit = ''
for line in inp:
    if len(line) == 1:
        unit = line[0]    # Sets the current unit (dict key) for upcoming lines
    else:
        di[unit].append(f"Code:{line[0]} desc: {line[1]}")  # Adds line to unit
print(di)
```

Outputs:

> ```
> {'Core Units':     ['Code:AB43342 desc: Identify learning objectives'],  
>  'Elective Units': ['Code:AB43343 desc: Engage with texts for personal purposes',  
>                     'Code:AB43344 desc: Engage with texts for learning purposes',  
>                     'Code:AB43345 desc: Engage with texts for employment purposes',  
>                     'Code:AB43346 desc: Engage with texts to participate in the community'],  
>  'Extra Units': ['Code:AB43348 desc: Create  texts for personal purposes',  
>                  'Code:AB43349 desc: Create  texts for learning purposes',  
>                  'Code:AB43350 desc: Create  texts for employment purposes']}
> ```